# Sort and display array values according to a value?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Given the following **PHP** array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Restaurant 123
            [city] => Arlington
            [zip] => 22201
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Bar Foo
            [city] => Ballston
            [zip] => 22201
         )
     [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Restaurant XYZ
            [city] => Ballston
            [zip] => 22201
         )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Restaurant 321
            [city] => Washington DC
            [zip] => 22201
         )

)
```

How can I produce a list sorted according to city (alphabetically), so that it would output something like:

**Arlington**

Restaurant 123

**Ballston**

Bar Foo

Restaurant XYZ

**Washington DC**

Restaurant 321

E.G., sorted first by city name alphabetically, and then by venue name, also alphabetically. Also note that it's not given that the restaurant name, nor the cities are alphabetically sorted in the array given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like theres two parts to what you want - sorting and displaying.

To sort, you want to use `usort` with small function defining the comparison

```
$sortFunc = function($a,$b) {return $a['city'] != $b['city'] 
                                 ? $a['city'] > $b['city']
                                 : $a['name'] > $b['name'];};

        // = function($a,$b) {return $a['city'] > $b['city'] || ($a['city'] == $b['city'] && $a['name'] > $b['name']);};
        // = function($a,$b) {return 100*strcmp($a['city'],$b['city']) + strcmp($a['name'],$b['name']);};
usort($arr, $sortFunc);

function displayNamesGroupedByCity($arr)
{
    $lastCity = '';
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        if ($v['city'] != $lastCity)
        {
             $lastCity = $v['city'];
             echo "<br /><strong>$lastCity</strong><br />";
        }
        else echo ', ';
        echo $v['name'];
    }
}

displayNamesGroupedByCity($arr);
```

For the hell of it im going to make things generic

```
function displayXgroupedByY($arr, $x, $y)
{
    $sortFunc = function($a,$b) use($x,$y) 
                               {return $a[$y] != $b[$y] 
                                 ? $a[$y] > $b[$y]
                                 : $a[$x] > $b[$y];};

    user($arr, $sortFunc);

    $lastCity = '';
    foreach($arr as $v)
    {
        if ($v['city'] != $lastCity)
        {
             $lastCity = $v['city'];
             echo "<br /><strong>$lastCity</strong><br />";
        }
        else echo ', ';
        echo $v['name'];
    }
    return $arr;
}

displayXGroupedByY($arr, 'name', 'city');
```

Comment: Hi Jon, I tried your sort function but a print_r($sorted) just gives me "1" instead of a sorted list? Apart from the missing apostrophes which I guess SO removed.

Comment: yes, i fixed it.  usort sorts in place, the return value is boolean

Comment: OK cool, this ALMOST works, except the items seem to be in reverse order, eg. both the cities and the venues are backwards?

Comment: hah i just noticed that myself.  you switched the comparisons to less thans i guess?

Comment: I just reversed the $a, $b in the $sortFunc = function() :)

Answer (score 2):

Write a callback function that you can pass to [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php), for example

```
function compare_venues($a, $b)
{
  return strcmp($a['name'], $b['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)**, which enables you to sort an array based on a user-defined comparison function.

Answer (score 2):

Try usort ( http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php ) where you can define a custom sort schema like

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

user defined sorting should do a work:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php